# get the currency value based on selected location from dropdownlist reactjs -redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a location dropdownlist. In my implementation, i have to show the currency based on location change in dropdownlist.**My data is like : [{mruCode: "1700", country: "US", countryText: "United States", division: "WORLDWIDE_INDUSTRIAL",currency:"USD"}....]**. If i am choosing the US it will show the USD  as a label. I have done so far.

action(load data):

```
export const loadData = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return axios.get(serviceUrl)
    .then(response=>{
      dispatch(getLocationData(response.data.mruPreferences))
    })
    .catch(error=>{
      throw(error);
    });
  };
};

export const currencyLists = mruCode =>({
  type: CURRENCY_LIST,
  payload: mruCode
});
```

reducer (load data)

```
case 'GET_DATA_SUCC':
           return{
               ...state,
               location:action.location
           }

case 'CURRENCY_LIST':
        let newState = Object.assign({}, state)
        let newCurrList = newState.location.filter((el) => el.mruCode === action.payload)
        return Object.assign({}, newState, {
            currList: newCurrList
        });
```

component code:

```
class LocationList extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            isLoading:false,
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.loadData();
    }

    handleChange(){
      this.props.currencyLists(mruCode);
    }

    render(){
      const{location}=this.props;
      console.log(this.props.currList);
      const _labels = store.getLabels();
        return(<div>
            <span className="btnElement_spacing">You are viewing pricing for </span> 
             <select id="toggleLocationName">
                                  {location.map(item =>
                   <option  key={item.id}  value={item} onClick={()=>this.handleChange(item.mruCode)}>{_labels[item.division]}</option>
                    )}
          </select> 
          <span className="btnElement_spacing"> in </span>
                  {this.props.currList.map((item,index)=><label id="toggle-currency" key ={index}>{item.currency}</label>)}
            </div>
             );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      location: state.locationRed.location,
      currList: state.locationRed.currList
    }
  }

  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      loadData:()=>{dispatch(loadData())},
      currencyLists:(mruCode)=>{dispatch(currencyLists(mruCode))}
      }
    }


  export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(LocationList);
```

Now, I am getting empty currList. How to get the currency from selected dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

When handleChange is fired, which is the value of `selectedOption`?

Comment: Hey man, if you're using Redux, you can store the data you receive in a Map. Turn the onChange event in: 
```
onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
```
`e` is the event and it contains also the value you stored in the single option. when you reach the reducer, pass the id of the data and get from there what dod you need using this id. I'm not sure I really understood what do you mean, I hope so. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Will you please check the code. I have edited with redux. Now, how i will get that currency. I am getting empty currList

Answer (score 0):

Does `location` on redux state is an Object(Map key-value) or an Array? Because if it is an Object you can't use the find method, but you should use it like:

```
case 'CURRENCY_LIST':
        let cList = state.location[action.id]
          return{
              ...state,
              currList: cList
          };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case 'CURRENCY_LIST':
    // Use object.assign to create a new object from a source.
    let newState = Object.assign({}, state)
    // Filtering the result by the id that has to be equal to the one you 
    // passed to the action. 
    let newCurrList = newState.location.filter((el) => el.id === action.id)
    // Returning a copy of the updated state, passing a third parameter 
    // (second source), that specifies the new value of currentList
    return Object.assign({}, newState, {
        currList: newCurrList
    })
```

I'm using object.assign, to respect one of the rules of Redux, that is to not change directly the state.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) you can find the doc for Object.assign method

Comment: Please add some commentary to your code in order to improve this answer.

Comment: Sure! But I would like to know if it resolved her/his problem

Comment: No. it is not working. I have tried with your answer.  But, i assume handle event is the main problem. But, bad luck not able to fix it.

Comment: You're passing a parameter to handleChange, but when you declared it, you didn't put any needed parameter